# Leadtools v13 annotations

Tags: leadtools-sdk

I'm currently working on an enhancement for a commercial utility that involves annotations with respect to LeadTools v13.  In terms of LeadTools, it would appear that most things start off with the raster object, but without documentation for V13, it's somewhat of a challenge to make heads or tails of how to proceed in terms of reading the annotation files in.

If anyone has any code examples for such an old version, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEADTOOLS support don't have online documentation for this old version of LEADTOOLS. However, our help files shipped with the toolkit includes code examples for most of our functions including the annotations functions. You can find our help files in the following folder:
[LEADTOOLS 13 Folder]\Help